# Dafny. Cannot establish the existence of LHS ... for sequences

Tags: dafny

For the following code I get that it cannot establish the existence of LHS values that satisfy the such-that predicate. How could I prove the right side holds and such an x exists?

```
method Main() {
  var n : int := 10;
  var x : seq<int> :| n == |x| && forall i :: 0 <= i < |x| ==> -1 <= x[i] <= 1; 
}
```

https://rise4fun.com/Dafny/TiO5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide a witness. The following assertion does the trick:

```
method Main() {
  var n : int := 10;
  assert |[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]| == 10;
  var x : seq<int> :| n == |x| && forall i :: 0 <= i < |x| ==> -1 <= x[i] <= 1; 
}
```

However, this brings you to the next point, which is that

Comment: This does not work ... I get `Error: this assign-such-that statement is too advanced for the current compiler; Dafny's heuristics cannot find any bound for variable 'x'`

Comment: I was intending to comment on this above as "the next point", but apparently my sentence got cut off somehow. This error message says that the verifier was now able to prove the existence of a value for `x`, but the compiler still couldn't figure out how to generate code for it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that even something trivial like this is not supported at the moment:

```
method Main() {
  var n : int := 10;
  var y : seq<int> :|  y  == [3];
  var x : seq<int> :|  x  ==  y;
  var z : seq<int> :| |z| == |y|;
}
```

Dafny manages to instantiate `x`, but not `z`.
Maybe post it in their [GitHub/Issues](https://github.com/Microsoft/dafny/issues)?

Comment: The verifier proves the existence of such a `y`, `x`, and `z`, but the compiler can't handle the last case. In general, one should expect that the verifier is not capable to finding all possible witnesses, so you may have to supply them yourself. One way for the compiler to handle a case like this would be to enumerate, at run time, all possible integer sequences until it finds one that satisfies the predicate. This will terminate, since the verifier has proved such a sequence exists. However, you would be disappointed with the run-time performance.

Comment: If you really do think the compiler's task is trivial, then please submit a pull request.